# Entity Framework Working with temporary objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF 4.1 and want to perform some checks using temporary objects.

The problem I've encountered is, that those objects are written back to the database as soon as I save any changes. I tried to detach the objects, but then the whole object graph gets shredded and I can't access the referenced objects which are required for the checks.

My code basically looks like this:

```
createTempOrder()
{
    Order order = new Order();
    order.Customer = dbContext.Customers.Single(c => c.ID == cID);
    dbContext.Detach(order);
    return order;
}
```

Are there any best practices to handle temporary objects in EF or do I need to override the detachment procedure?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want EF to track your entities you can use AsNoTracking() method:

```
order = dbContext.Orders.AsNoTracking().Single(o => o.ID == oID);
```

Of course this works if Order is an entity managed by EF.

Comment: My Order is not contained in the database. Itshould only exist in code, which is why i can´t set the notracking property

Comment: If I understood right what you're trying to achieve, you can create a new Context instance just to perform those checks and then dispose it. In this way the changes you make shouldn't be "visible" in other contexts.

Comment: I still need the referenced objects in another context. After the checks on the order are completed the customer entity is added to a report which is then added to the database.